# Excel to Script - Array, ArrayList, Hashmap?

Tags: java, excel, hashmap

I have an excel in the following format

```
  customers  users
  customer1  user1
  customer1  user2
  customer2  user3
  customer3  user4
  customer3  user5
```

I'm parsing the above into an array of strings. I need it to be in a string like this

```
script.bat -c customer1 -u user1 user2
script.bat -c customer2 -u user3
script.bat -c customer3 -u user4 user5
```

essentially I want to check for all "customer 1" and add any users associated with "customer 1" to the string. The string is easy but to get them there I wasn't sure if it was best to use a Hashmap or something similar where I can easily compare and find values.

Comment: `Map<String,List<String>>` would be fine I think. `HashMap` is good as the map implementation, and `ArrayList` for the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map` to compile your unique customers with your users then loop over the map and format your `String`s.

Example using your inputs as a `String[]`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String[] strings = {"customer1  user1",
        "customer1  user2",
        "customer2  user3",
        "customer3  user4",
        "customer3  user5"};

    final Map<String, Set<String>> concatentatingMap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>() {
        @Override
        public Set<String> get(Object key) {
            Set<String> strings = super.get(key);
            if (strings == null) {
                strings = new LinkedHashSet<>();
                put((String) key, strings);
            }
            return strings;
        }
    };

    for (final String s : strings) {
        final String[] split = s.split("\\s++");
        concatentatingMap.get(split[0]).add(split[1]);
    }
    final MessageFormat messageFormat = new MessageFormat("script.bat -c {0} -u {1}");
    for (final Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : concatentatingMap.entrySet()) {
        final String customer = entry.getKey();
        final StringBuilder usersBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        final Iterator<String> iter = entry.getValue().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            usersBuilder.append(iter.next());
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                usersBuilder.append(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(messageFormat.format(new Object[]{customer, usersBuilder.toString()}));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
script.bat -c customer3 -u user4 user5
script.bat -c customer2 -u user3
script.bat -c customer1 -u user1 user2
```